# How to add custom mysql database in symfony

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine, symfony1, symfony-1.4

First of all hello everyone !

I'm on a Symfony 1.4 website, and I don't really have knowledge in this framework.

The site already uses 2 database connections, in databases.yml

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name
      username: my_username
      password: ***
      charset: utf8
      encoding: utf8
      attributes:
        default_table_collate: utf8_general_ci
        default_table_charset: utf8
        use_native_enum: true

# Base de test
test:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_other_db_name
      username: my_username
      password: ***
      charset: utf8
      encoding: utf8
      attributes:
        default_table_collate: utf8_general_ci
        default_table_charset: utf8
        use_native_enum: true
```

It's working I think, well I never use base test but I guess it works.
I need to use another database, not in localhost this time but from another server.
I tried so many thing, that i learn from stackoverflow post.

I created a config folder into my module, where I put the code into a new databases.yml

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      mysql:host=mysql_host.bdb;dbname=mysql_db_name
      username: mysql_username
      password: ***
      charset: utf8
      encoding: utf8
      attributes:
        default_table_collate: utf8_general_ci
        default_table_charset: utf8
        use_native_enum: true
```

I don't know how to access to this database, seems to not working at all.
So I try directly into my template, seems logic because I need this database only into 1 template, in response of a form.

```
$bd_nom_serveur='mysql_host.bdb';
$bd_login='mysql_user';
$bd_mot_de_passe='***';
$bd_nom_bd='mysql_db_name';

$base = mysqli_connect($bd_nom_serveur, $bd_login, $bd_mot_de_passe, $bd_nom_bd);
```

Sending me warning

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql_host.bdb' (2) in /srv/d_/www/draft.site.com/apps/frontend/modules/FormContactSlot/templates/sendMailCatalog.php on line 14

I also tried

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=mysql_db_name;host=mysql_host.bdb';
$user = 'mysql_user';
$password = '***';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dbh);
```

sendig me error

> 500 | Internal Server Error | PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005]
>   Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql_host.bdb' (2)

I try with and without .bdb but nothing change.
I don't know how to access to this database from symfony 1.4

Can anyone help me please !
keep in mind that I have very little knowledge of Symfony, be gentle please !

### EDIT :

I also tried another trick.
I add the database after my principal database on config/databases.yml

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name
      username: my_username
      password: ***
      charset: utf8
      encoding: utf8
      attributes:
        default_table_collate: utf8_general_ci
        default_table_charset: utf8
        use_native_enum: true
  client:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      mysql:host=host.bdb;dbname=dbname
      username: user
      password: ***
      charset: utf8
      encoding: utf8
      attributes:
        default_table_collate: utf8_general_ci
        default_table_charset: utf8
        use_native_enum: true
```

And this time I got an error whenever I try to go on my website. I also do the command `symfony doctrine:build-schema` but this send me the same error unknown mysql server...
Please I need help, I have to access my mysql database from symfony, I don't have the choice.

Comment: `host.bdb` is hostname. Your DNS server must resolve this to an IP address, and this is not happening. Where did you get it from?

Comment: So you mean I use the bad value for dbname ? I should use an IP address instead of db name.
I get it from my manager OVH. I got 4 databases and I need to access to one. I got 1 IP address but to access at the domain, not at the databases.
I can access them from phpMyAdmin only, and with the dbname/user/password only I guess. And if I need an IP address I don't know where to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I respond to myself because I find a solution :

### There is no solution.

I'm on a shared OVH solution, and shared OVH databases are not remotely accessible. So I have to take a vps solution, where there is IP host for database.

Thanks to Marek for helping me finding the solution.
Here the query that works.

```
$bd_nom_serveur='IP host';
$bd_login='mysql_user';
$bd_mot_de_passe='***';
$bd_nom_bd='mysql_db_name';

$base = mysqli_connect($bd_nom_serveur, $bd_login, $bd_mot_de_passe, $bd_nom_bd);
```

PDO still not working.